# Uploading Files with WebServices hosted on IIS--> Best Practises

Tags: .net, web-services, web-applications

We have an application for which UI is built on Flex, and its consuming webservieces built on Dotnet hosted on IIS. we are trying to upload files which are around 100/200 megs , this works like a charm on LAN , if we try to do the same with web service hosted on public ip machines , then this would fail very often(obviously bcoz of lesser bandwidth ) . we have tried increasing executionTimeout(up to 10 minutes) maxRequestLength (up to 200 megs) , this didn't help . so we were thinking what would be the best way to approach this problem , and also what are the best practices which are used in this space.

Thanks for your inputs.

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Please say if you're using WCF or the old ASMX web services. Also, what versions of IIS and .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Web services aren't the ideal way to do file upload and download. You'd be better off sticking with a protocol that was designed for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , what protocol are you taking about , could you elaborate a bit?